# How to download text file from button on click

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, system.xml, frontend-model

How to download text file from button on click . I created Button in my system.xml i define frontend Model i want to download text file when i click on button .below is the code i am using

```
              <test_request translate="label">
                    <label></label>
                    <frontend_type>button</frontend_type>
                    <frontend_model>module/system_config_form_test</frontend_model>
                    <sort_order>17</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>0</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                </test_request>
```

test.php

```
  public function getButtonHtml()
    {
        $button = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_button')
            ->setData(array(
                'id'        => 'kems_export',
                'label'     => $this->helper('adminhtml')->__('Export License Request'),
                'onclick'   => 'javascript:exportTest(); return false;'
            ));

        return $button->toHtml();
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `onclick` with:

```
'onclick'   => 'setLocation(\''.Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('*/*/downloadTextFile') . '\')',
```

then in your **etc/config.xml** add:

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Namespace_Modulename before="Mage_Adminhtml">Namespace_Modulename_Adminhtml</Namespace_Modulename>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

and finally create **Namespace/Modulename/controllers/Adminhtml/System/ConfigController.php**:

```
class Namespace_Modulename_Adminhtml_System_ConfigController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function downloadTextFile()
    {
        $fileName   = 'test.txt';
        $content    = 'test content';
        $this->_prepareDownloadResponse($fileName, $content);
    }
}
```

I didn't test it but it should work. Of course replace Namespace_Modulename with your module name.

Comment: error is coming after addding the above code 404 Error Page not found.

Comment: yes its working